# How to include JARs in WAR archive WEB-INF/lib using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, war

My Maven `pom` file builds a `war` without the dependencies, so that i have to manually add them to the WEB-INF/lib.

Is there any way to instruct Maven to include all the dependencies within the `war` ? **So the the `war` become self content and independent**

Comment: Depending on the scope of your maven dependencies, Maven includes the jars automatically in the war file. You need to post your pom.xml if help is needed with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure the type of your pom is `war`. Maven's default behavior is ***to copy*** dependencies in the lib folder. 
P.S.
If you found any trouble post your full pom.
Besides see [maven war plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) for further doc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make sure the packaging is of type war like `<packaging>war</packaging>`. Also check if the dependencies in your pom are of the right scope, for example if they are not default or the compile scope, that's possibly why they are not bundled into the war's lib folder.

```
<dependency>
 ..
 ..
 <scope>compile</scope>
<dependency>
```